# Shortest Possible 100 Mile Race Prep

Tags: long-distance-running, running-training-plan, marathon, ultramarathons

Hey all I'm planning on doing a 100 mile race in February (about 12 weeks out). I've read online that BARE minimum theoretical race prep was like 9 weeks but they didn't provide a plan for that. Anybody recommend a schedule to run to make that it in 12? I can't find a prep for 12 weeks so maybe an experience runner (maybe even an ultra runner out there?) would want to try to modify one and if so I would be super grateful for the help!

Current fitness level is that i'm pretty active (mostly with weights) and I ran a marathon without any prep in 7 hours last month, so I figure with 12 weeks and a lot of luck I can get the 100 in 12 weeks. I am aware this is rushing it and not a great idea, i'm just looking for a conductor to help me steer this trainwreck to the finishline :D. The goal is to finish in 30 hours

Comment: Most marathons I know of have a cut-off time of 6 hours. If you finished it in 7, you didn't run, you just walked. And running 100 miles in 30 hours is harder than you might think. Without proper training, it can be really dangerous. You might have heart problems, kidney failure, stress fractures, long-term joint problems, gastrointestinal problems, etc. It's a dumb idea. Just follow a marathon training plan and finish one with a decent time and then think about training for ultras. You probably won't even be able to sign up for one anyway, since they usually require a decent marathon time.

Comment: @Wood Well mine had a cutoff of 7 hours, so I aimed for 7 hours and hit it. There is no previous requirements for the ultra in February. I would appreciate you answering the question if you are able to, if not then thanks for the concern, but I will look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

#### Long overdue

- Here is a 12-week plan with [more info on this link](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/42932/50-km-30-mi-march-in-a-week-how-to-prepare/42998#42998) yet I would not recommend you to neither follow the plan nor do any ultras based on the very limited information that you've provided in your question:

[image]

[image]

- Ultras are for those who can at least finish a road marathon below 3:00/3:30 hours and they have an athletic/excellent [Rest Heart Rate](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/expert-answers/heart-rate/faq-20057979#:%7E:text=A%20normal%20resting%20heart%20rate%20for%20adults%20ranges%20from%2060,to%2040%20beats%20per%20minute.).
- You might want to speak to a medical doctor for that.
- If you would have sufficient physical capacity, you might want to practice and plan for one full year to reduce your marathon hours. Then, see where would you stand and take it from there?

#### Disclaimer:

- Everything here is at your own risk. Neither a licensed trainer nor a doctor.

### Good luck and happy running!! ( ˆ_ˆ )

---

#### Reference

- [Camille Herron Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Herron)
- [Camille Herron Site](http://www.camilleherron.com/)