# 50 km / 30 mi march in a week - how to prepare?

Tags: cardio, training, walking, marathon

I've got a 30 mile march in a week. It's not a race but there's a time limit of 12 hours to finish the course. I'm quite fit and took part in a similar event last year, but my girlfriend is less fit and is a bit apprehensive.
What could we do now to improve our chances of survival? :)
I know one can't train in the very last minute but we've had a lot of plans changed and cancelled due to COVID...
We'll do a long(-ish) hike this weekend (something like 14 miles), then do some shorter hikes next week. Our gear (boots) is tried and tested, but I'm curious what would be the best regimen for the last seven days before the event...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For seven days, just very light trainings/rest would suffice.
- I think you'll both make it hopefully since the time limit of 12 hours is too high.

#### For the Next Time: Prepare in Advance

- It's just a bit longer than marathon, here is a [12-weeks training plan](https://www.shape.com/fitness/training-plans/your-12-week-marathon-training-plan) for marathon to give you a big picture of how the prep should look like. However, you should not follow these trainings, as is, because it's a bit professional and you'd most likely get injured. **Tone it down very much, as much as you can handle/bear (based on your physical capacities)**.
- Cross train and tempo are pretty important for you.

[image]

[image]

---

#### Key Goal: Not to Get Injured

- Your goal should be not to get injured at all time ( ˆ_ˆ ). Staying away from injury is the most critical goal for newbies.
- Whatever you do, focus on not getting injured whatsoever.
- You should start working on both speed and endurance in the same week.
- If you have the time which I don't think you do, you can exercise multiple times a day.
- I'd suggest you would start jogging instead of walking.
- Swimming is quite helpful if you are into that.
- Biking is also not bad.
- Read about how to run correctly.
- Buy good sneakers (with lots of cushion) and lightweight running shirts/shorts/jackets, good athletic socks, etc.

#### Basics

In every session, follow these:

- 15 minutes of stretching before each exercise
- Warming up for 15 minutes after stretching
- Do the exercise
- 5 to 15 minutes (depending on the intensity) cooling down after each exercise
- 15 minutes of stretching after cooling down

---

#### Disclaimer:

- Measure your Rest Heartbeat every morning and check out your progress with a certified trainer/ doctor
- Everything here is at your own risk. Neither a licensed trainer nor a doctor.

### Good luck and happy marathoning!! ( ˆ_ˆ )

Comment: Wow thanks Emma for your very detailed answer! Will be helpful next time :) As for this march - we've successfully finished it in about 11:30... no injuries but my GF couldn't walk faster. For comparison - when I did it alone last year, I finished the course in 8:30 :)

Comment: @Alexander You're welcome! Congrats! That's very good.